# How do I configure chronograf to run in a specific port?

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python, chronograf

I am a newbie in InfluxDB.

I have installed InfluxDB and Chronograf in `C:/InfluxDB/` and created this structure:

- `C:/InfluxDB/influx-data`
- `C:/InfluxDB/influxdb`
- `C:/InfluxDB/chronograf-1.8.4-1`

I execute influxd.exe. Everything OK
I execute chronograf. Everything OK

Nevertheless, when I am running a Jupyter notebook on port `8888`...and try to execute chronograf it crashes because it uses the same port.

I would like to change chronograf to another port for example in `8083`.

I have tried to run this command in the cmd: `chronograf -p=8083` but it returns to me this:

`time="2020-05-28T12:02:41+02:00" level=error msg="Invalid basepath, must follow format \"/mybasepath\"" basepath=invalid component=server`

I have read the documentation of Chronograf and found this:

- ***--basepath= | -p The URL path prefix under which all chronograf routes will be mounted. Environment variable: $BASE_PATH***

But I still don't understand which URL is referring to, nor how to set BASE_PATH...

I would appreciate a concrete example with a "real" url and not /your_base_path which doesn't help me to understand.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

--port option is for setting port number, like this:

```
chronograf --port=8083
```

-p is short form of --basepath= option and it's used like this

```
chronograf --basepath=/chronograf
```

it causes chronograf to be accessible under following address: **http://127.0.0.1:8888/chronograf** instead of default **http://127.0.0.1:8888**

More options can be found here: https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf/v1.8/administration/config-options/

When running it as a service on linux preferred way to change port is to edit file **/etc/default/chronograf** to have conntect like this:

```
PORT=8083
```

This way modification aren't lost when updating.